# Linq query 'Id in query' how to?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

Is there any tweek to use IN like query in lambda?
for example i have a query

```
Select * from Users where Id in ( 1,45,67, 89)
```

can i write the same in linq?
for example i have list of user say

```
List<Users> oUserList= new List<Users>();
```

and i have int list

```
List<Int32> Ids
```

and i want to write query like

```
var data= select all users from 'oUserList' where id not in 'Ids'
```

can any body tell me how to write this?

thanks

**Issue solved**

```
var data = oUserInfolist.Where(x => (!oo.Contains(x.ID)));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from u in oUserList where !Ids.Contains(u.UserID) select u
```